# GridView Lags Too Much

Tags: android, performance, gridview

I have a GridView in my app which loads images from "drawables" folder, there are about 17 images (960x600) but the problem is,                                                                                   i am unable to scroll properly because it lags too much!

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

  // Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
  mContext = c;
  }

public int getCount() {
  return mThumbIds.length;
 }

public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

  // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ImageView imageView;
  if (convertView == null) {
  imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
  } else {
  imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
  }

  imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
  return imageView;
   }

   // Keep all Images in array
  public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
  R.drawable.sample_0, 
  R.drawable.sample_1,
  R.drawable.sample_2, 
  R.drawable.sample_3,
  R.drawable.sample_4, 
  R.drawable.sample_5,
  R.drawable.sample_6, 
  R.drawable.sample_7,
  R.drawable.sample_8, 
  R.drawable.sample_9,
  R.drawable.sample_10, 
  R.drawable.sample_11,
  R.drawable.sample_12, 
  R.drawable.sample_13,
  R.drawable.sample_14, 
  R.drawable.sample_15,
  R.drawable.sample_16, 
  R.drawable.sample_17  

  };
   }
```

Comment: Are each of the images 1900x1500? Is there a reason they need to be that big? With images that size, you might get out of memory exceptions on some devices

Comment: is 960x720 suitable for all screens? i want to set the images as wallpaper

Comment: I would propose you scale images and load them in to the GridView, then when they select one, use a larger image to set as the wallpaper. You'll notice a speed increase if you're loading in smaller bitmaps for each view you're loading in the GridView

Comment: As images are pushed out of view they are flagged as available for garbage collection. This means they need to be reloaded when they come back in to view. If everything was kept in memory you would run out quickly!

Comment: is there any way for loading all the images at once and cache them?

Comment: If you scale down the images, you'll see a significant enough speed increase that you won't need to do that. They aren't loaded from a network resource, so it would be just as fast as disk caching.

Comment: i have scaled down the images to 960x600 but still, i'm facing the same problem, i want to stop it loading again and again and cache it. is that possible?